# Octave keeps crashing on start-up

Tags: path, io, package, octave, startup

I tried to install the io package ( https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/index.html ) from the octave command window, for some reason this didn't work the 1st time and Octave just crashed. I restarted Octave and tried again, this time it didn't crash but the function in the "io" package was still undefined.

I figured it might be an error with the package not being on the path, so I made sure to add packages to the path with subfolders. I then moved it to the bottom (I know some items must be at the top of the path list).

That seemed to work, because after `pkg list` it would now appear in the list of installed packages. I double checked it was on the path and hit save and then Octave started repeatedly printing errors that various functions were "shadowing core-functions" it would do this non-stop for a bit and then crash.

I can't troubleshoot it (or even provide the exact error messages) because it crashes too quickly. Octave was installed correctly and I experienced no crashing issues until after this issue with the functions contained in the io package today.

After googling, I found that somebody had resolved an issue with Octave crashing on start-up by deleting the "history" file in "AppData\Roaming\octave"
This did not work either.

Is there any way to resolve this WITHOUT a clean reinstall of Octave?

Comment: Just to be clear, after the io package installed without crashing, it couldn't find the package functions even after running `pkg load io`?

Comment: Yes, I used that line and the functions the package contains were still undefined. I am wondering if there is a way to fix this issue without reinstalling Octave altogether. The warnings that appear on start-up say that a long list of functions "shadows a core library function" and says the warning was called from ".octaverc at line 2 column 3" 
it does this for many functions and then Octave crashes (before I can do further investigation). I have never encountered this error when installing packages before.

Comment: The warnings are normal and expected when you're loading functions with the same name as a core function. Many packages do this. E.g, loading the statistics package will "shadow" several core functions because they have more functionality than the core versions. So, you need to figure out why you're autoloading functions at startup. The .octaverc clue points to you having a pkg load or path change command in one of your .octaverc startup files. Look for them at the places listed here, and try commenting out the problem line when you find it: https://docs.octave.org/latest/Startup-Files.html